# Polymer 2.x: Wrapping external JS library in ES6 web component

Tags: javascript, polymer, es6-class, es6-modules, polymer-2.x

I am trying to wrap [the progressbar.js library](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io) inside an ES6 web component using Polymer 2.0.

I get the following error message.

console.error

> render-status.html:54
>   
> Uncaught TypeError: ProgressBar.SemiCircle is not a constructor
>   
> at HTMLElement.animateCircle (progress-bar.html:108)
>   
> at HTMLElement. (progress-bar.html:85)
>   
> at callMethod (render-status.html:51)
>   
> at runQueue (render-status.html:42)
>   
> at render-status.html:29

[Here is a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyy8craL/1/) of the following code I'm attempting to wrap inside the Polymer element.

src/progress-bar.html

```
<link rel="import" href = "../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href = "shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href = "progressbar-js.html">

<dom-module id="progress-bar">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10 px;
      }
      p {
        font - size: 200 % ;
        font - family: Roboto, Open Sans, sans - serif;
      }
      .label {
        color: #6FD57F !important;
        font-size: 300%;
        font-family: Roboto, Open Sans, sans-serif;
      }
      #container {
        width: 200 px;
        height: 100 px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">1</div>
      <div id="container"></div>
      [[animatePercentage]]
      <p>1,234 steps</p>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class ProgressBar extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'progress-bar';
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          animatePercentage: {
            type: Number,
            notify: true,
            value: 0.7,
          },
        }
      }

      constructor() {
        super();
      }

      ready() {
        super.ready();
        Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, function() {
          //...
        });
      }

      connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.animateCircle('container', this.animatePercentage);
      }

      animateCircle(containerId, animatePercentage) {
        var startColor = '#FC5B3F';
        var endColor = '#6FD57F';

        var element = document.getElementById(containerId);
        var circle = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(element, {
          color: startColor,
          trailColor: '#eee',
          trailWidth: 5,
          duration: 2000,
          easing: 'bounce',
          strokeWidth: 5,
          text: {
            value: (animatePercentage * 100) + '%',
            className: 'label'
          },
          // Set default step function for all animate calls
          step: function(state, circle) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
          }
        });

        circle.animate(animatePercentage, {
          from: {
            color: startColor
          },
          to: {
            color: endColor
          }
        });
      }

    }

    window.customElements.define(ProgressBar.is, ProgressBar);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

src/progressbar-js.html

```
<script src="../bower_components/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't it because you define a new ProgessBar class/proto: `class ProgressBar extends Polymer.Element {` and then try to call a method that doesn't exist 'anymore' `new ProgressBar.SemiCircle` ?

Comment: @Booster2ooo: My thinking is running along those lines. I'm wondering if I need to import a behavior perhaps? I thought the `link import` would might be sufficient. Do you have any suggestions for the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm not very confortable with web components so I might be wrong but still, here is what I see. You import the progressbar.js library, that defines a `ProgressBar` prototype/class that you can use to build shapes: `new ProgressBar.SemiCircle`. But then, after importing this library, you say, ok now `ProgressBar` will be a new proto/class that extends `Polymer.Element`, destroying the previous one you loaded. So, it hits `animateCircle` and `new ProgressBar.SemiCircle`,  `SemiCircle` doesn't exist anymore. You should try renaming your class to `PolymerProgressBar` to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: Futhermore, I don't know if it's intended but you load an HTML file, not a JS file for progressbar: `<link rel="import" href = "progressbar-js.html">`

Comment: @Booster2ooo: I edited the question to make it clear I am importing the JS library via the html file per recommended best practice.

Comment: just a guess but could it be that you are somewhere using AMD or CommonJs?
// If you aren't using any module loader, progressbar.js exposes
// global variable: window.ProgressBar
=> if you are using a loader I guess it won't exposes to window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by a name conflict between your `ProgressBar` class and the `ProgressBar` symbol added by `progressbar.js`. Renaming your class (e.g., to `MyProgressBar`) would resolve the error you're seeing.

As a side note, `animateCircle()` uses `document.getElementById(containerId)` to fetch the container element, but that method can't query the element's shadow DOM, which is where the element lives. You can easily fix that with this Polymer shorthand: `this.$[containerId]`.

```
// var element = document.getElementById(containerId); // DON'T DO THIS
var element = this.$[containerId]; // DO THIS
var element = this.shadowRoot.getElementById(containerId); // OR DO THIS
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jmQLyV?editors=1010)